# GridView_RowUpdating returning old values

Tags: asp.net, gridview, event-handling

I have a grid view in which there is functionality to update/delete rows. I am storing the data to SQL using stored procedure. When I click on Edit button and change the existing value and after clicking Update button I am getting old values.

My code is :

```
protected void grdNatureFormation_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();            
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)grdNatureFormation.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("btnUpdate");
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(link.CommandArgument);
    TextBox title = (TextBox)grdNatureFormation.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTitle");
    if(title != null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection Sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())                
            {
                Sqlcon.Open();
                cmd.Connection = Sqlcon;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "NatureOfFormation";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = title.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Action", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = "update";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                grdNatureFormation.EditIndex = -1;
                LoadData();
            }
        }
    }            
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}

private void LoadData()
{
    ConnectionString = GeneralMethods.GetConnectionString();
    SqlConnection Sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        Sqlcon.Open();
        cmd.Connection = Sqlcon;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "xxx";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Action", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
        cmd.Parameters["@Action"].Value = "select";
        SqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        SqlAda.Fill(ds);
        grdNatureFormation.DataSource = ds;
        grdNatureFormation.DataBind();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            Sqlcon.Close();
        Sqlcon.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

}
```

I searched over internet for the issue and most of the posts suggest to place the data binding method in the `(!Page.IsPostBack)` , but in my case it is already in the same condition but not getting value.

What should I do to get new value in `RowUpdating` event?

Comment: share your `LoadData()` code..

Comment: Is there anything wrong done by me?@SidM

Comment: no i don't think anything is wrong with your code, i'm also trying the same example as your code on my machine.. can you tell me your that `LoadData()` is being called after your`grdNatureFormation_RowUpdating` ? set debugger on `LoadData()` and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`RowUpdating` is called **before** the gridview values are updated. You need to put your code into the `RowUpdated` event handler.

For more info, see the manual: [GridView Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx)

**RowUpdating** - Occurs when a row's Update button is clicked, but before the GridView control updates the row.

**RowUpdated** - Occurs when a row's Update button is clicked, but after the GridView control updates the row.